# System_Daemon::setSigHandler

Tags: php, pear, signals

I am using system daemon inside a class,
I am wondering if the following code for setting a handler is ok or not

```
System_Daemon::setSigHandler(SIGTERM, array($this, myShutdownHandler) );
```

in the documentation they don't mention how to pass an object method as a **"handler"**
here: array($this, shutdownHandler)

the qiven example in the docs:

```
System_Daemon::setSigHandler(SIGTERM, "ownShutdownHandler" );

function ownShutdownHandler($sig)
{
 //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks OK.

Example code can be found on https://github.com/kvz/system_daemon/blob/master/examples/bug_test_b.php

Answer (score 0):

The "handler" is known as a "callback" in the PHP world. Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/callback).